# OOD: order.fill(warehouse) -or- warehouse.fill(order)

Tags: oop

which form is a correct OO design?
"Matter of taste" is a mediocre's easy way out.
Any good reads on the subject?
I want a conclusive prove one way or the other.

**EDIT:** I know which answer is correct (wink!). What I really want is to see any arguments in support of the former form (`order.fill(warehouse)`).

Comment: What about abstractOrderExecutionFactory.fill(order, warehouse)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no conclusive proof and to a certain extent it is a matter of taste. OO is not science - it is art. It also depends on the domain, overall software structure, etc. and so your small example cannot be extrapolated to any OO problem.

However, here is my take based on your information:

Warehouses store things. They don't fill orders. Orders request things. They don't know which warehouse (or warehouses) the things come from. So a dependency in either direction between the two does not feel right.

In the real world, and the software, something would be a mediator between the two. @themel indicated the same in the comment to your question, though I prefer something less programming pattern sounding. Perhaps something like:

```
ShippingPlan plan = shippingPlanner.fill(order).from(warehouses).ship();
```

However, it is a matter of taste :-)

Comment: see my answer for the argument why your suggestion is valid, but not necessary.

Comment: I understand that DI is an improvement when it is warranted. In this case question is not how to improve it, but to pick one over the other. Actually, I want to know if there is a domain where `order.fill(warehouse)` is a better choice at all.

Answer (score 0):

In its simplest form warehouse is an inventory storage place.
But it also would be correct to view a warehouse as a facility comprised of storage space, personal, shipping docks etc. If you assume that view of a warehouse then it would be appropriate to say that a warehouse (as a facility) can be charged with filling out orders, or in expanded form:

a warehouse facility is capable of assembling a shipment according to a given specification (an order)

above is a justification (if not proof) for: `warehouse.fill(order);` form. Notice that this form substantially equivalent to SingleShot's and themel's suggestions. The trick is to consolidate `shippingPlanner` (an order fulfillment authority) and a warehouse (a inventory storage space). Simply put in my example warehouse is a composition of an `order fulfillment authority` and an `inventory storage space` and in SingleShot's those two are presented separately. It means that if such consolidation is (or becomes) unacceptable (for example due to complexity of the parts), then the warehouse can be decomposed into these two sub components.

I can not come up with a justification for assigning `fill` operation to an `order` object.

*hello? warehouse? yes, please take this order and fill it. thank you.* -- that I can understand.

*hey, order! the warehouse is over there. do your thing and get fulfill yourself.* -- makes no sense to me.